# How to get the point(CGPoint) of the selected sectionIndexTitle

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How to get the point(CGPoint) of selected sectionIndexTitle in tableView?I didn't find any way to achieve this.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    //How to get the point of the selected sectionIndexTitle
    return index;
}
```

Is it possible that there is a method to get the selected sectionIndexTitle Object? So I can access it's frame and change it's color.

Comment: get point means CGPoint or else

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Yes, point means CGPoint, I have edited the description;

Comment: I am not sure , in here we can . get

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do get the CGpoint of the cell. Create a block and whenever user tap on the cell. Use the below code to get the CGPoints

let touchPoint = CGPoint(x: cell.center.x, y: cell.center.y)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but What I want to get is the CGPoint of the selected sectionIndexTitle , not the cell.